# How to make MongoDB query with $or

Tags: javascript, mongodb, find

I'm trying to return a user from a MongoDB collection that either matches the supplied username OR email:

```
db.users.find({
    $or:[
        {username: "user1"},
        {email: "mail@mail.com"}
    ]
});
```

This query returns an empty result even though

```
db.users.find({username: "user1"});
```

or

```
db.users.find({email: "mail@mail.com"});
```

Returns the same object, how do I format the query to make it optional to supply the username or email?

Comment: the or syntax looks fine - this works for me.

Comment: Yes it does for me too now, I had version 1.2.2
 and upgraded to version 1.6.5, now it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or operator become with 1.5.3 version of mongodb.

From [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries):

> $or
>
> The $or operator lets you use a
>   boolean or expression to do queries.
>   You give $or a list of expressions,
>   any of which can satisfy the query.
>     **New in MongoDB 1.5.3**

So problem was in old version of mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.2.2 does not seem to fully support $or, version 1.6.5 does.